# Windows phone UWP apps - Image Cloud Storage

Tags: c#, windows-10-mobile, cloudinary

I'm currently looking for a free Cloud storage Image service like Cloudinary to upload pictures from my app and to have access to them without authentification like a public folder.

The issue that I'm facing is that no one of those I have tried have a framework integration compatible with windows phone uwp.

For exemple when I try to install the package CloudinaryDotNet with 
NuGet i got this error : Some packages are not compatible with UAP.
And the installation fail.
I tried with the Google Drive package but it failed to.

How do you upload your pictures from your windows phone Uwp app ?

Thank to anyone who will time to answer to me  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm Itay from Cloudinary, unfortunately we couldn't reproduce the error message you referred to. We'll check UWP and consider to support it in the future. In the meantime, note that the upload to Cloudinary is a simple `POST` request, uploads can be done either signed or unsigned, client-side or server-side. Please see the following for more information:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_api

After the images are already stored on your Cloudinary account, you can transform, optimize and deliver/download them simply by a `GET` request of their URLs: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations